# Android WebViewClient not OverridingURL

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I would like to `catch local anchor clicks`. These anchors are local within the page i.e., `href="#link_1"`. What is the best way to catch these clicks? `OverrideURL` does not fire on them? I am loading a new page based on the anchor href.

Comment: I'm debating adding a javascript interface to deal with each anchor click. This seems like the long way around. Do page anchors trip shouldOverrideUrlLoading?

Comment: i found similar issue with webview..opening such href links. did you find a solution?

Comment: my page was internal to the device so I had to change the href="#anchor" to href="file:///android_asset/webassets/link.html#anchor". This was the only way to get the anchors to work properly. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer somewhere ,redirects can be intercepted by shouldOverrideUrlLoading provided u are using API level 11 or greater.

Answer (score -2):

In which version, you are running this program. 
I found this issue with ICS. 
In ICS, shouldOverrideUrlLoading() is called, only when I tried to load a wrong URL using Webview.
So, you can use this behavior for a quick fix.

Comment: Your answer is a little confusing. Clarify your answer and format the code.